# How to do form validation using bootstrap validator like stepper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys i am looking forward to do form validation using bootstrap validator.
In my design i have three tabs, the functionality should be like
on page load only the first tab should be open when the user clicks on next all elements of first tab should be validated then only second tab should open. the same way if the user clicks on finish form should sent to server

https://jsfiddle.net/ym3yk38m/4/

```css
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 6px solid #DDD; }
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus,.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {border: none;background:#f8f8f8; } .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0;background:#f8f8f8;}
.nav-tabs > li > a { border: none; color: #666; padding:10px 95px; width:500px; }
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover { border: none;background:#f8f8f8; }
.nav-tabs > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #00a8a8; height: 7px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s; transform: scale(0); }
.nav-tabs > li.active > a::after, .nav-tabs > li:hover > a::after { transform: scale(1); }
.tab-nav > li > a::after { background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: #fff; }
.tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
.tab-content{padding:20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    
     <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 
 <!--bootstrapValidator-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    
<!-- Date picker css -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation"
   style="margin-bottom: 0">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
     data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
      class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
   </div>
   <!-- /.navbar-header -->

   <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
   </ul>
   <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
   <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">  
      
     </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
  </nav>
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-wrapper">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h3 class="page-header">
       <b>Student Self Enrollment</b>
      </h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                         <li class="col-lg-4 role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Info</a></li>
                                        <li class="col-lg-4 role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Info</a></li>
                                        <li class="col-lg-4 role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Previous Educational Info</a></li>                                    
                               </ul>       
       </div>
       <!-- /.panel-heading -->
       <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <div class="tab-content">
                    
          <!--Personal info tab div -->
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
          <h3 style="color: red">Student Details</h3>
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Name</label>
           <!--<div class="group">-->
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.studentFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentFirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
            
           </div>           
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.studentMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
            
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">            
            <input name="student.studentLastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentLastName" placeholder="Last name" />
            
           </div>          
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3 ">
            
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">             
             <input name="student.studentDOB" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Date-Of-Birth" />
             
             <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Gender</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
             <label class="btn btn-default">             
             <input type="radio" name="optradio">Male</label>
              <label class="btn btn-default"> 
              <input type="radio" name="optradio">Female</label>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Place of Birth </label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.studentBirthPlace" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentBirthPlace" placeholder="Place of Birth" />
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Mother Toungue</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.studentMotherTounge" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentMotherTounge" placeholder="Mother Toungue" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Blood Group </label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.studentBloodGroup" type="text" class="form-control" id="studentBloodGroup" placeholder="Blood Group" />
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Class Name</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">            
              <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Image</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="student.studentImage"/>
           </div>
          </div>

          <h3 style="color: red">Parent Details</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Father Name</label>
           <div class="group">
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.fatherFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fatherFirstName" placeholder="First name" />
            
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.fatherMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fatherMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
            
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.fatherLastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fatherLastName" placeholder="Last name" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Mother Name</label>
           <div class="group">
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.motherFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="motherFirstName" placeholder="First name" />
            
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.motherMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" id="motherMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
            
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.motherLastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="motherLastName" placeholder="Last name" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Gaurdian Name</label>
           <div class="group">
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.gaurdianFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="gaurdianFirstName" placeholder="First name" />
            
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.gaurdianMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" id="gaurdianMiddleName" placeholder="Middle name" />
            
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.gaurdianLastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="gaurdianLastName" placeholder="Last name" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Occupation</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="parent.occupation" type="text" class="form-control" id="occupation" placeholder="Occupation" />
            
           </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Qualification</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.qualification" type="text" class="form-control" id="qualification" placeholder="Qualification" />
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Income</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.income" type="text" class="form-control" id="income" placeholder="Income" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Nationality</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.nationality" type="text" class="form-control" id="nationality" placeholder="Ex: Indian"/>
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Religion</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.religion" type="text" class="form-control" id="religion" placeholder="EX: Hindhu Muslim..."/>
            
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Caste</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.caste" type="text" class="form-control" id="caste" placeholder="Ex:Okkaliga,Lingayath"/>
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Category</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="student.category" type="text" class="form-control" id="category" placeholder="Ex:3a,2a...."/>
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-11 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-20 ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
           </div>           
          </div>                           
          </div>
          
          <!--Contact info tab div -->
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Phone Number</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.phoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
            
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Emergency Contact</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input name="parent.emergencyContact" type="text" class="form-control" id="emergencyContact" placeholder="Emergency Contact" />
            
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="parent.emailID" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            
           </div>
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Permanent Address</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">            
            <textarea class="form-control" name="student.permanentAddress" rows="5" cols="30" />
           </div>
           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Present Address</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="student.presentAddress" rows="5" cols="30" />
           </div>
          </div>

         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-11 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-20 ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
           </div>           
          </div>
        </div>
          
          <!--Previous Educational info tab div -->
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">School Name</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="student.previousSchoolName" type="text" class="form-control" id="schoolName" placeholder="Previous School Name"/>
            
           </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">From</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3 ">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="from">
             <input name="student.fromYear" type="text" class="form-control" id="from" placeholder="From Year"/>
             
             <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
           </div>

           <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">To</label>
           <div class="col-xs-3 ">
            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="to">
             <input name="student.toYear" type="text" class="form-control" id="to" placeholder="To Year"/>
             
             <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Reason for Change</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="student.reasonForChange" type="text" class="form-control" id="reasonForChange" placeholder="Reason for Change"/>
            
           </div>
          </div>

           
          
          <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Tc Document</label>
           <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="student.tcDocument"  />
           </div>
          </div>      
 
           <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-11 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-xs-20 ">
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success">Finish</button>
           </div>           
          </div>                 
          </div>          
                                    </div>         
         </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.form-body -->
       </div>
       <!-- /.panel-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
 </div>
```